# Pandas: Create view on MultiColumn object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set a value on a multi columned table. However, I appear to be working on a copy, as the value does not persist:

```
In[4]:     tIndex = np.array([32, 34, 134, 234, 334, 434])
    topColumns = ['homogenous', 'heterogenous']
    mus = ['mu_el', 'mu_eh', 'mu_ul', 'mu_uh']
    bottomColumns = mus + ['Jl', 'Jh', 'v', 'u']
    arrays = [topColumns, bottomColumns]
    #tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
    columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays)

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index=tIndex)
In[6]: df.loc[32, 'homogenous']['v'] = 1
In[8]: df.loc[32, 'homogenous']['v']
Out[8]: nan
```

The case of a multi-index inside `.loc[]` is trivial and mentioned extensively in the documentation. However, how do I work with a view with a multi-columned data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass tuple to represent the different levels:

```
In [125]:
df.loc[32, ('homogenous','v')] = 1
df

Out[125]:
    homogenous                                       heterogenous              \
         mu_el mu_eh mu_ul mu_uh   Jl   Jh    v    u        mu_el mu_eh mu_ul   
32         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   
34         NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   
134        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   
234        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   
334        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   
434        NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN          NaN   NaN   NaN   


    mu_uh   Jl   Jh    v    u  
32    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
34    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
134   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
234   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
334   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  
434   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

it looks you're doing chained indexing

Comment: It's really inconsistent that a multi-index requires no tuples, but a multi-column does.